# Is there a name for polymer structures that resemble a foldable lattice?

Tags: polymers

I'm struggling to find the right descriptors for this, but it would look like this

[image: advert for foldable trellis made from criss-crossed pieces of wood that hinge where they cross over]

I've been doing some layperson reading up on stretchy materials, and I know a lot of them work by the polymer chains unraveling (for lack of a better term), but I wondered if any such polymer could be arranged more like the pictured lattice?

Comment: It would have some [rotaxanes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotaxane) connecting linear chains? I doubt something like that was made. In principle, it's possible, but in practice, likely pointless.

Comment: "stretchy" materials are usually 3D networks, usually not regular as you show, but with a wide distribution of mesh sizes. By swelling in what would be a good solvent for the given polymer without the network links, you can extend the chains of each mesh.

Comment: @Mithoron I agree it's likely pointless, but is there a general name for this sort of lattice structure? It's nothing like this, but layered graphene sheets at angles seem to be called a [superlattice](https://phys.org/news/2018-03-rotated-magic-angle-graphene-sheets.html)... Is there an equivalent term for the overall structure here?

Comment: @Karl yeah I imagine if it ever existed, it would be in solution, in the same way that rubber is often modeled as polymer chains in 'solution' only interactive via van der Waals forces? I'm not sure what you're saying in your second sentence... specifically 'swelling' and 'chains of each mesh'...?

Comment: If this was what I mentioned, and your post is specific enough to be sure, you could call it a [mechanically interlocked molecular architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanically_interlocked_molecular_architectures), more precisely [supramolecular polymer network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supramolecular_polymer)

Comment: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/cr9000622

Comment: @Mithoron yeah, MIMA and the term 'Supramaolecular' both cropped up when I went looking at related articles to your roxatanes link. I also came across [Foldamer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foldamer) and [Polymer architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymer_architecture) which seem like helpfully related articles.

Comment: Oh, I meant your q. is *not* specific enough. One could draw various analogies and a single bond can rotate better than some roxatane.

Comment: @Mithoroen the the crux of my question is, is there a name for when long chains assemble into a separate macro scale lattice where this kind of hinging/pivoting/rotating in some part of the chain lets its go from the squashed folded up version to the extended version. There may not be  catch all name, but if there's a specific name for one thing like it and not all, that's still a good answer right?